# How to send a crash report in Fabric by default without user interaction?

Tags: ios, google-fabric, crash

We are using Fabric for our iOS App which will work best and helping us 
to solve our major problems very quickly and easily.

We had some feedback from users after every app crash in next app launch fabric asked user to “send crash report” , “Don’t send report” and “always send report” options, most of our users thinks again app getting crashed.

Is it possible to send crash report by default without asking user to send crash report?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You should give the user the opportunity to not send a crash to you - they may regard their crash state as sensitive data they would rather withhold from you. Could you implement this as an option in a Preferences panel, to avoid asking the user explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

What your users see appears to be the built-in "Send Crash Report?" alert from Crashlytics. AFAIK, this is only shown when you have enabled the "Privacy Prompt" in your app's dashboard in Fabric.

You should either turn this setting off, or implement your own control over when crashes are sent, see the docs at https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#control-submission-behavior